# Implementing a text area for an e-mail field?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

Basic question but I can't get it to work. I'm making a form on RoR with the help of some Bootstrap. I've looked around but I can't see any documentation on how I would be able to make an HTML email field (i.e ) into a text-area.

Reason: I'm expecting multiple emails in this area and thus would like to display all or most of them instead of a single input text line cutting off half of the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your passing  block you can do something like this

f.text_area :email, size: "60x12"

Hope that helps

Comment: But that still utilizes the text_area element of HTML and just gives it the key email, I'm looking for utilizing the email_area of HTML5.